# Appending pandas Data Frame to Google spreadsheet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-sheets, gspread

Case:
My script returns a data frame that needs has to be appended to an existing google spreadsheet as new rows of data.As of now, I'm appending a data frame as multiple single rows through gspread.

My Code:

```
import gspread
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()

# After some processing a non-empty data frame has been created.

output_conn = gc.open("SheetName").worksheet("xyz")

# Here 'SheetName' is google spreadsheet and 'xyz' is sheet in the workbook

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    output_conn.append_row(row)
```

Is there a way to append entire data-frame rather than multiple single rows?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I can recommend [`gspread-dataframe`](https://github.com/robin900/gspread-dataframe):

```
import gspread_dataframe as gd

# Connecting with `gspread` here

ws = gc.open("SheetName").worksheet("xyz")
existing = gd.get_as_dataframe(ws)
updated = existing.append(your_new_data)
gd.set_with_dataframe(ws, updated)
```

Comment: doesn't this overwrite the "existing" data as well, making it overwhelming if we are adding, for example, 5 new rows to a 1000 row table?

Comment: Yes, this approach loads the existing google sheet data to your local machine, appends to it locally, and finally writes the whole shebang back to your google sheet. [It looks like](https://github.com/robin900/gspread-dataframe/blob/master/gspread_dataframe.py#L137-L163) you COULD append by using the `row` parameter to `set_with_dataframe`, but then you better trust your column order :-)

Comment: I have found a better solution - using the values_append from the gspread package. This appends values in one call without the need to replace current data in the sheet.

Comment: @DarkTemplar that sounds cool! If you can take the time, please add a standalone answer to it can bubble up into common knowledge :-)

Answer (score 6):

Here is the code to write, append(without loading the existing sheet into memory), and read to google sheets.

```
import gspread_dataframe as gd
import gspread as gs
gc = gs.service_account(filename="your/cred/file.json")

def export_to_sheets(worksheet_name,df,mode='r'):
    ws = gc.open("SHEET_NAME").worksheet("worksheet_name")
    if(mode=='w'):
        ws.clear()
        gd.set_with_dataframe(worksheet=ws,dataframe=df,include_index=False,include_column_header=True,resize=True)
        return True
    elif(mode=='a'):
        ws.add_rows(df.shape[0])
        gd.set_with_dataframe(worksheet=ws,dataframe=df,include_index=False,include_column_header=False,row=ws.row_count+1,resize=False)
        return True
    else:
        return gd.get_as_dataframe(worksheet=ws)
    
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([{'a': i, 'b': i * 2} for i in range(100)])
export_to_sheets("SHEET_NAME",df,'a')
```

---

1. Write Mode: First clear existing worksheet => `ws.clear()`
   .Second using `set_with_dataframe()` uploading the dataframe,
   here note that `resize=True`, which strictily set the row and col in worksheet to df.shape. This will help later in append method.
2. Append Mode: First, add rows according to the dataframe. Second setting the parameter `resize=False` as we are adding rows and `row=ws.row_count+1` anchoring its row value for append.
3. Read Mode(Default): returns a dataframe

Comment: Interesting Share: There is this package https://github.com/betodealmeida/shillelagh which provides a SQL interface to Google Sheets. We can INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT rows directly from Google Sheets.

Comment: Hey Darsh I tried your code but during the `append mode` it always returns an error do you happen to know why?: `gspread.exceptions.APIError:
{'code': 400, 'message': 'Range (test!A999:B1001) exceeds grid limits. Max rows: 998, max columns: 26', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}`

Comment: Did some testing and noticed `row_count` returns empty rows as well. This causes the exception. I would suggest to tweak the code by using `max_rows = len(sheet.get_all_values(major_dimension='rows'))` instead of `row=ws.row_count`. This way the data will be appended at the end of the non-blank cells

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same problem, here's what I did
converted the dataframe into list and used gspread's `append_rows()`

```
    gc = gspread.service_account(filename="credentials.json")
    sh = gc.open_by_key('<your_key>')
    ws = sh.sheet1
    
    ##data is the original data frame
    data_list = data.values.tolist()
    
    ws.append_rows(data_list)
```

Answer (score 3):

The following approach, using [`gspread`](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/), may help one understand the procedures and solve the problem

1. Install the libraries in your environment.
2. Import the libraries in the script

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   import gspread
   from gspread_dataframe import set_with_dataframe
   ```
3. Create credentials in [Google API console](http://gspread.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2.html).
4. Add the following to the script, to access the Google Sheet

   ```
   gc = gspread.service_account(filename='GoogleAPICredentials.json')
   sh = gc.open_by_key('GoogleSheetID')
   ```

Assuming one wants to add to the first sheet, use `0` in `get_worksheet` (for the second sheet use 1, and so on)

```
worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(0)
```

5. Then, in order to export the dataframe, considering that the dataframe name is `df`, to a Google Sheet

   ```
   set_with_dataframe(worksheet, df)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I came up with the following solution. It does not overwrite current data but just appends entire pandas DataFrame `df` to the end of Sheet with name `sheet` in the Spreadsheet with the name `spread_sheet`.

```
import gspread
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

def append_df_to_gs(df, spread_sheet:str, sheet_name:str):
    scopes = [
        'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    ]
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        path_to_credentials,
        scopes=scopes
    )
    gsc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
    sheet = gsc.open(spread_sheet)
    params = {'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED'}
    body = {'values': df.values.tolist()}
    sheet.values_append(f'{sheet_name:str}!A1:G1', params, body)
```

For params `valueInputOption` please consult [this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption). I used `USER_ENTERED` here as I needed some formulas to be valid once I append the data to Google Sheets.

Answer (score 1):

```
ws = gc.open("sheet title").worksheet("Sheet1")

gd.set_with_dataframe(ws, dataframe)
```

#simply transform your dataframe to google sheet

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following solution using try/catch statement, in case the spreadsheet doesn't exsit he will create it for you and set the dataframe otherwise he will append it.

```
def load_to_sheet(conn_sheet, spreadsheet_name, df):
try:
    worksheet = conn_sheet.worksheet(spreadsheet_name)
    worksheet.add_rows(df.shape[0])
    set_with_dataframe(worksheet=worksheet, row=worksheet.row_count, dataframe=df, include_index=False,
                       include_column_header=False,
                       resize=False)
except Exception:
    worksheet = conn_sheet.add_worksheet(title=spreadsheet_name, rows=100, cols=100)
    set_with_dataframe(worksheet=worksheet, dataframe=df, include_index=False, include_column_header=True,
                       resize=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following doesn't require external libs other than gspread:

```
worksheet.update([dataframe.columns.values.tolist()] + dataframe.values.tolist())
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving upon the solution given by Darsh Shukla

```
def append_df_to_sheet(g_spread_name, sheet_name, df):
    
    wks = gd.set_with_dataframe(worksheet= self.gc.open(g_spread_name).worksheet(sheet_name) # get the sheet
    append_row = wks.row_count+1 # position where to append
    wks.add_rows(df.shape[0]) # add rows to avoid API range error
    gd.set_with_dataframe(worksheet= self.gc.open(self.g_spread_name).worksheet(sheet_name), # refresh the sheet   
                dataframe=df,
                include_index=False,
                include_column_header=False,
                row = append_row,
                resize=False)
    return True
```

This avoids the error

```
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Range (test!A999:B1001) exceeds grid limits. Max rows: 998, max columns: 26', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}
```

Answer (score -2):

if Google spreadsheet takes .csv format then you can convert a pandas dataframe to csv using df.to_csv() and save it in that format