# Writing dataframe to blank google spread sheet

Tags: python, dataframe, google-sheets

I want to write a dataframe to blank google sheet I tried solution from [Appending pandas Data Frame to Google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540827/appending-pandas-data-frame-to-google-spreadsheet) but output is weird.

```
sheet = client.open('product matrix').sheet1
existing = gd.get_as_dataframe(sheet)
updated = existing.append(registrations)
gd.set_with_dataframe(sheet,updated)
```

getting output like 
Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 10 Unnamed: 11 Unnamed: 12 Unnamed: 13 Unnamed: 14 Unnamed: 15 Unnamed: 16 Unnamed: 17 Unnamed: 18 Unnamed: 19 Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 20 Unnamed: 21 Unnamed: 22 Unnamed: 23 Unnamed: 24 Unnamed: 25 Unnamed: 26 Unnamed: 27 Unnamed: 28 Unnamed: 29 Unnamed: 3  Unnamed: 30 Unnamed: 31 Unnamed: 4  Unnamed: 5  Unnamed: 6  Unnamed: 7  Unnamed: 8  Unnamed: 9  dated   registrations

Comment: Saying 'weird' doesn't help to solve the problem. Please add the output you got.

Comment: I'm having this same issue, have you solved it?

Comment: from gspread_dataframe import set_with_dataframe  set_with_dataframe(sheet,df,include_column_header = True,resize=True)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm a bit late, if I understand this correctly, you want to remove the `Unnamed: <number>` stuff, right? I've had the same issue myself. If so, this happens because you're appending the dataframe onto existing columns and rows in the Google Sheet. If you remove the part where you append, you should not get anything with the `Unnamed: <number>`. The following should work:

```
sheet = client.open('product matrix').sheet1
existing = gd.get_as_dataframe(sheet)
gd.set_with_dataframe(sheet,existing)
```