# Converting pandas Dataframe to Google spreadsheet

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets

I followed this answer to this question ([Appending pandas Data Frame to Google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540827/appending-pandas-data-frame-to-google-spreadsheet)) to append by dataframe to an empty google spreadheet. Some data is being added to it but not how I want:

code:

```
#complete_dict is just a dictionary I created from JSON 
df = pd.DataFrame(complete_dict).fillna(value='0').T

        convert_to_csv = df.to_csv('C:/Users/Elitebook/Documents/GitHub/test3.csv')
        print df

        scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

        credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('C:/Users/Elitebook/Documents/GitHub/TrackRev-caad86be6e44.json', scope)


        file = gspread.authorize(credentials)
        #create the empty spreadsheet
        new_spreadsheet = file.create('CSV-test-6')
        #this step is necessary so we can view the spreadsheet
        new_spreadsheet.share("charlesdsmith25@gmail.com", perm_type='user', role='writer')

        #after the spreadsheet is created, open it
        spreadsheet = file.open('CSV-test-6').sheet1

        existing = gd.get_as_dataframe(spreadsheet)
        updated = existing.append(df)
        df_spreadsheet = set_with_dataframe(spreadsheet, updated)
```

This is what my dataframe looks like:

```
          add_classes add_grades change_classes     ...     delete_grades view_classes view_grades
principle           1          0              1     ...                 0            1           1
student1            0          0              0     ...                 0            1           1
student2            0          0              0     ...                 0            1           1
teacher             0          1              0     ...                 1            1           1
```

But this is what the spreadsheet looks like:

```
Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 10 Unnamed: 11 Unnamed: 12 Unnamed: 13 Unnamed: 14 Unnamed: 15 Unnamed: 16 Unnamed: 17 Unnamed: 18 Unnamed: 19 Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 20 Unnamed: 21 Unnamed: 22 Unnamed: 23 Unnamed: 24 Unnamed: 25 Unnamed: 3  Unnamed: 4  Unnamed: 5  Unnamed: 6  Unnamed: 7  Unnamed: 8  Unnamed: 9  add_classes add_grades  change_classes  change_grades   delete_classes  delete_grades   view_classes    view_grades
```

No rows and way too many columns and the values (1s and 0s) aren't there

Comment: Looks like you are not setting the index df.set_index(0)

Comment: My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67737742/7109869) may help you understand what is being done and how to export a df to a Google Sheet.