# How to append data to google spreadsheet using Python

Tags: python, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api, gspread

**Problem :** I have an incremental data which I need to append to my google spreadshseet at beginning of each month.
Code that I tried :

**Trial 1**

```
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
#creds.json is the credentials file
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('drd_creds.json', scope)
gd = gc.authorize(credentials)

wks = gd.open_by_key('1lONS0lTy-XXXXXXXXXXX').worksheet("worksheet_name")
set_with_dataframe(worksheet,df_adsets)
```

The above code doesn't append but overwrites the spreadsheet.

**Trial II** : 
As per the guidance given in [Appending pandas Data Frame to Google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540827/appending-pandas-data-frame-to-google-spreadsheet)

```
wks = gd.open_by_key('1lONS0lTy-XXXXXXXXXXX').worksheet("worksheet_name")
existing = get_as_dataframe(wks)
updated = existing.append(df_adsets,sort=True)
set_with_dataframe(wks,updated)
```

```
 Problem: The method gets all the rows and columns of the spreadsheet 
(empty ones too as NAN) and when it appends the data there is a weird formatting done for e.g. 

1. original value: 23843372759610279 changes to 2.38E+16
2. Column orders are changed to alphabetic order 
3. Also, it seems to be a very crude method of getting all the data then appending then writing back.
```

Is there any function from gspread or any other library to append values/data frame directly rather than overwriting ? (I don't want to write individual rows but just write the whole df from the next empty row).

Comment: Change your `set_with_dataframe` method to append instead of overwrite...

Comment: https://github.com/robin900/gspread-dataframe/blob/80cf07fc147909a356712d08e6e80ee6a2c0e9f4/gspread_dataframe.py#L137-L144