# df2gspread is missing an attribute to upload a pandas dataframe to google sheets, is there a workaround?

Tags: python, pandas, df2gspread

I'm trying to upload a pandas dataframe to google sheets, and I'm following this step by step guide:https://towardsdatascience.com/using-python-to-push-your-pandas-dataframe-to-google-sheets-de69422508f

I'm using the df2gspread to upload the dataframe, however the I get an error saying this attribute:

https://df2gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#df2gspread.df2gspread.upload

doesn't exist?

[image: picture of the error here]

I tried df2gspread.df2gspread.upload, which then gave me this error[image: screenshot here]

I have tried

```py
dict(vars(df2gspread)).keys()
```

which gave me the output

```py
dict_keys(
    [
        "__name__",
        "__doc__",
        "__package__",
        "__loader__",
        "__spec__",
        "__path__",
        "__file__",
        "__cached__",
        "__builtins__",
    ]
)
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I invite you to look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61092662/uploading-pandas-dataframe-to-google-spreadsheet

Comment: Thank you, the answer seems to suggest that I'm not installing it correctlly, however when I put You are not importing the package properly.

Just do this

from df2gspread import df2gspread as d2g I get the error :
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'df2gspread'

Comment: https://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/pythonquestions/73396-ModuleNotFoundError-No-module-named-df2gspread.html#:~:text=pip%20install%20df2gspread